# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Could not process parameters: str(3), it must be of type list, tuple or dict

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I have created a Tkinter desktop app and one of the button is to delete many selected students from the student list. These student record is connected with MySQL database. When I have selected 2 records from the student list to delete, the below error incurred.

```
def delete_many():
     if response == 1:
        sel = record_table.selection() 
        ids_to_delete = []
       
        for record in sel:           
            ids_to_delete.append(record_table.item(record, 'values')[0])
            
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host = 'localhost',
        database = 'students',
        user = 'root',
        password = '',
        auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
        )

        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        
        sql_command = 'DELETE FROM student WHERE student_id in %s'
        
        sel_data = [a for a in ids_to_delete]
        
        mycursor.executemany(sql_command, sel_data)
                
        mydb.commit()
        mydb.close()

search_bar_frame = Frame(root)
search_bar_frame.pack()
delete_many = Button(search_bar_frame, text='Delete Many', font=('Bold',12),  
                    relief=GROOVE, command=delete_many)
delete_many.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=20, padx=40)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kelvin Loh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "d:\Learning App\Tkinter\student_delete_mysql.py", line 151, in delete_many
    mycursor.executemany(sql_command, sel_data)
  File "D:\Learning App\Tkinter\tkinter_venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 375, in executemany
    self.execute(operation, params)
  File "D:\Learning App\Tkinter\tkinter_venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py", line 263, in execute
    prepared = self._cnx.prepare_for_mysql(params)
  File "D:\Learning App\Tkinter\tkinter_venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 728, in prepare_for_mysql
    raise ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Could not process parameters: str(3), it must be of type list, tuple or dict

How to fix it?
```

Comment: Try `student_id = %s` instead of `student_id in %s` in the SQL statement.

Comment: mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Could not process parameters: str(3), it must be of type list, tuple or dict

Comment: You need to use `sel_data = [(a,) for a in ids_to_delete]` instead as well.